Please help with the Delete Unique Permissions button - it creates big problems for us
I have twice now accidentally clicked the "Delete Unique Permission" when I meant to remove one person's access. This has cost our company time-- and time is money. It also has damaged my reputation as someone that made this mistake.
Please make some edits to SharePoint to allow us to block the button from myself and others.
Can SharePoint create at least a warning box that pops up that asks "You are about to delete permissions for all user groups? Are you sure you want to remove everyone's access?" To make me and others pause before accidentally deleting everyone's access.  Better yet would be to allow us to control that button that creates so many problems and loss of productivity for our staff.
